# Encode query string in Nginx

Tags: nginx

I have Nginx in front of Gunicorn.

But I'm getting request where some of the query parameters are un-encoded like this:

```
 &userUA=Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 11_2_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/604.1.34 (KHTML, like Gecko) GSA/73.1.246847905 Mobile/15C153 Safari/604.1
```

Which causes Gunicorn to throw an error.

Is there a way I can encode the query string in Nginx?

Comment: Eh? The query string should already be encoded. How did you get an un-encoded string?

Comment: @MichaelHampton It's being send via an API it aren't browser requests. And I have no possibility on getting the api to change.

Comment: It is not your responsibility if someone uses the API incorrectly. They should fix their code.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Yes that's how it should be done. But that's not possible. Is there a solution on my end?

Comment: No, it is not possible. Your developer must make fixing the client possible.